# Import from one Java project to another Java project

Tags: java, import, package, project

My problem is about importing a project.

I can use one Java class in other Java class in one package.

[image: example]

I can import one Java class from first package to other Java class from other package.

[image: example]

But I want something different. I want to import from first big project to other big project.

Not between classes, not between packages!

I try to watch YouTube video and to research, but i didn't find answer to my question.

Comment: How are you managing your project? Are you using Maven or Gradle?

Comment: @ndc85430 I actually dont know what means (Maven and Gradle)
I am begginner xD
But i just want to associate  two projects

Comment: You will need to package your project as a `jar` and then put the `jar` in the classpath of the project you want to import it to. Maven and Gradle make this much easier, but i also recommend reading the oracle docs to see the barebones method: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/

Comment: @TheBest, I don't know anything of your background, experience, etc., but I'm wondering if you're making things harder for yourself right now? If you're just beginning, would it make more sense to have everything in the same project and just use packages to organise the code? More advanced things can come later.

Comment: Thanks,i try to improve my skill and i will come again here